# UIView scroll view scrolls out of way

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Is there a way you can (probably using UIScrollView) scroll another UIScrollView down so all you see is like 55px (or whatever value you want) at the bottom. So for example you have UIScrollView in the background that scrolls horizontally (contains BGs). You can scroll horizontally in that to change the BG. on top of that you have a UIScrollView (vertically scrolling) with content. If the user scrolls up so much it would scroll down the actual UIScrollView down to the bottom of the screen (it would keep the top 55px visible) and remains there like a little tab, allowing the user access to the BG scroller to change the BG. But then they can (using the tab) scroll back up and the UIScrollView goes back to full screen and they can scroll the content UIScrollView again.

For example the google maps app on android, if you go to a place, you get a "tab" of the view at the bottom and you can drag it up and then scroll in it, and then drag it back down. It stays there at the bottom and you can drag it back up at any time, but it gives you access to the view behind it (the map in that case)

Comment: The idea you present sounds reasonable.  Restrict the content size of the vertically scrolling scroll view to be (2 * view.bounds.size.height) - tabHeight, which is the height of the "tab" you want to keep at the bottom.

Comment: @danh the problem with that is then the vertical scrollview is still capturing the touch input so the horizontal one won't recognize that the user is trying to scroll horizontally

Comment: The scroll views should take care of that (see here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html)

Comment: @danh the problem is the frontmost scrollview (vertical) shouldn't scroll horizontally. Like its on top of the horizontal one. There is only 1 vertical one. The horizontal one is to change the background (the frontmost scrollview has transparent BG).